# In Next.js, fetch does not return new data, it returns existing data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, next.js13

I'm trying to use fetch as SSG method in Next.js.

However, the value of 'content' that I registered in the mock server is different from the value that is actually displayed.

Below is my code.

```
import Layout_Mobile from "@/components/Layout/DeviceLayout/Layout_Mobile";
import Layout_PC from "@/components/Layout/DeviceLayout/Layout_PC";
import PostDetailPage from "@/components/PostDetailPage/PostDetailPage";

const fetchPosts = async (params) => {
  const res = await fetch(
    `https://5875183d-18c0-49ad-b99d-8deeb4ded6a9.mock.pstmn.io/posts/${params.slug}`
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      return data;
    });

  return res;
};

export const generateStaticParams = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(
    "https://5875183d-18c0-49ad-b99d-8deeb4ded6a9.mock.pstmn.io/posts"
  )
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((data) => {
      return data;
    });

  return res.map((post) => ({
    slug: post.id.toString(),
  }));
};

const page = async ({ params }) => {
  const { title, summary, content, author, createdAt } = await fetchPosts(
    params
  );

  return (
    <div>
      <Layout_Mobile></Layout_Mobile>
      <Layout_PC>
        <PostDetailPage
          title={title}
          description={summary}
          content={content}
          author={author}
          date={createdAt}
        />
      </Layout_PC>
    </div>
  );
};

export default page;
```

The result I expected(The value I entered in postman. That is, a new value)

```
{
  "content": "test1 "
}
```

Actual Results(Value previously registered)

```
{
  ...previous json data
}
```

How do I solve this problem?

Thank you for reading it.

I tried SSG but it failed... I want to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are facing has to do with the way Next.js caches individual fetch requests. When you statically generate the pages at build time and do not provide any of the below options besides the first one, **only the cached result will ever be returned** after the first fetch.

You have a different options you can pass onto each request to define their behavior:

---

###### Force Cache

This request should be cached until manually invalidated, similar to the way `getStaticProps` is only called once (at build time) inside the pages router. This is the default and applied if omitted.

```js
const response = await fetch("https://api.example.com", {
  cache: "force-cache",
});
```

###### No Store

This request should be refetched on every request. similar to the way `getServerSideProps` is called for each request inside the pages router.

```js
const response = await fetch("https://api.example.com", {
  cache: "no-store",
});
```

###### Revalidate

This request should be cached for a lifetime of 10 seconds before being invalidated. Similar to `getStaticProps` with the `revalidate` option inside the pages router.

```js
const response = await fetch("https://api.example.com", {
  next: { revalidate: 10 },
});
```

---

You can find more about these different behaviors in the [official documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/fetch).